# Pass array value to database with order

Tags: javascript, php

I just pass my lat, lng to mysql database with order. Here is the code for posting data to the database:

```
for (var i = 0; i < latLngs.length; i++) {
  $.post('send.php', {
      username: name,
      latitude: latLngs[i].lat,
      longitude: latLngs[i].lng
    }, function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
    });
}
```

And send.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['username'];
$lat = array($_POST['latitude']);
$arrlength = count($lat);
$lnt = array($_POST['longitude']);
$link = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect");
@mysql_select_db("beta") or die("cannot select db");
for ($x = 0; $x <$arrlength; $x++) {
    $query="insert into belcheer(username,lat, lng) values('$name','$lat[$x]','$lnt[$x]')";
    @mysql_query($query) or die("cannot run query");
}
@mysql_close($link);
?>
```

and here is my original data from from user [input from user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmF1Q.png) but the data in the database is not in the correct order [not ordered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7kw6.png). How do I solve this problem?

UPDATED!
when i insert data to database it multiplied. I mean my array length is 4 but database record is become 16. Why it is happened?

```
for ($x = 0; $x <count($lat); $x++){
    $query="INSERT INTO belcheer(username,lat, lng) VALUES('user','$lat[$x]','$lng[$x]')";
    @mysql_query($query) or die("cannot run query");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you order it in send.php at the server side? Of apply some ordering algo on latLngs before running for loop.

Comment: @Ankit + You should add a timestamp to order it. Inserting to a DB not provides you any stack-like option

Comment: `$.post` is asynchronous, so you are making every call before the previous have ended. Probably some data is being inserted before some other that was sent before.

Answer (score 2):

A browser uses a connection pool for sending requests to the server, so multiple posts/requests will happen simultaneously with the possibility that a later requests is processed first by the server, which is what you see.

You can only enforce the correct order if each post waits for the previous post to complete.

Since you also implement `send.php`, you're best option is send all data in one request:

**JavaScript**

```
$.post('send.php', { username: name, latLngs: JSON.stringify(latLngs) }, function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
});
```

**PHP**

```
$latLngs = json_decode($_POST['latLngs']);
// Now you can work with $latLngs array in PHP
```

Comment: Probably because you post your data 4 times, remove your for-loop in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the fact that those POST calls are executed simultaneously -- well, almost simultaneously, anyway -- and are processed by the server in the order they *happen* to come in.

You'll need to figure out a way to ensure that the `$.post` calls are made sequentially (one after each other), in the order you want.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because $.post is executed asynchronously. This means that even though you make your requests in order, it doesn't mean that they will be received by the server in the same order they are sent.

Your best option is to make a single request where you send the whole array at once and then process the array server side

Comment: i can't imagine how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your function to synchronous like this:

```
function sendGeo(latLngs,index){
    if (latLngs[index]!== undefined)
    {
        $.post('send.php', {username:name, 
                            latitude:latLngs[index].lat,
                            longitude:latLngs[index].lng}, 
        function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
            sendGeo(latLngs,index++); //use the callback to send next data
        });
    }
}

sendGeo(latLngs,0);
```